# Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

In my project I use three tab to show three activities in single screen. 
Tab 1 - Map

Tab 2 - Games

Tab 3 - Imageflipper

 When I select tabs in series like Map--->Games--->Imageflipper then It work fine.

But when I select back to any tab like Map--->Games--->Imageflipper--->>Games,  Then it show me error-

Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment.

Screen shot of Emulator:

http://s9.postimg.org/jdjsxnswf/Untitled.png

This is my logcat.

```
03-26 05:48:09.876: D/AndroidRuntime(1094): Shutting down VM
03-26 05:48:09.876: W/dalvikvm(1094): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.example.image_changer.TopRatedFragment.onCreateView(TopRatedFragment.java:15)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1264)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1012)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:523)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:495)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:476)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.example.image_changer.MainActivity1.onTabSelected(MainActivity1.java:82)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:570)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java:1067)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java:519)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Duplicate id 0x7f050010, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:285)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
03-26 05:48:09.936: E/AndroidRuntime(1094):     ... 30 more
03-26 05:48:14.426: I/Process(1094): Sending signal. PID: 1094 SIG: 9
03-26 05:48:15.578: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:15.578: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:15.656: I/System.out(1203): you are in on create in main activity
03-26 05:48:16.306: D/dalvikvm(1203): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 74K, 7% free 2616K/2812K, paused 51ms, total 53ms
03-26 05:48:16.576: D/dalvikvm(1203): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 6% free 3025K/3200K, paused 111ms+102ms, total 262ms
03-26 05:48:16.736: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:16.736: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:16.746: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:16.776: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:16.966: D/libEGL(1203): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
03-26 05:48:17.056: D/(1203): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a187918, tid 1203
03-26 05:48:17.376: D/libEGL(1203): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
03-26 05:48:17.407: D/libEGL(1203): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
03-26 05:48:18.176: W/EGL_emulation(1203): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-26 05:48:18.997: D/OpenGLRenderer(1203): Enabling debug mode 0
03-26 05:48:18.997: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.018: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.026: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.176: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.186: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.218: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.218: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.226: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.226: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.226: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0  
03-26 05:48:19.436: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.436: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
03-26 05:48:19.436: W/Trace(1203): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

By clicking on package name related error in Logcat, It show me these error.

First in MainActivity1.java
    `View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);`

Second in Topratedfragment.java
    `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());`

This is MainActivity1.java file

```
package com.example.image_changer;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity1 extends FragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Map", "Games", "Image flipper" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        /*MainActivity1.this.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ee7b35")));


    System.out.println("you are in oncreate in mainactivity1");

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    System.out.println("you are in onTabreselected");
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    System.out.println("you are in onTabunselected");
}

}
```

This is my TopRatedfragment.java file

```
package com.example.image_changer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

    return rootView;
}
}
```

I tried this solution-

When I change `extends` `Fragment` to `FragmentActivity` in Topratedfragment.java then it give me error- `The method onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) of type TopRatedFragment must override or implement a supertype method`. `Remove override notation` as quick fix. 

When I remove override notation it give a error in Tabspageradapter.java class and error says - Type mismatch: cannot convert from TopRatedFragment to Fragment and change method return type to `TopRatedFragment` and may be this is not useful to me.

```
package com.example.image_changer;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
 super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new TopRatedFragment();


    case 1: 
        return new GamesFragment();

    case 2:
        return new MoviesFragment();

    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 3;
}
}
```

This is GameFragment.java class

```
package com.example.image_changer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class GamesFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_games,container,false );


    return rootView;
}


}
```

Then how to solve this problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of this code in TopRatedfragment.java solve this problem:

```
private static View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
if (view != null) {
    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
    if (parent != null)
        parent.removeView(view);
}
try {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
} catch (InflateException e) {
    /* map is already there, just return view as it is */
}
return view;
}
```

Comment: uh oh, static views means memory leaks, careful

Comment: i was looking for a solution for the past 4hrs thanks so much! But why does it work? Weirdest thing was, that it was working fine for weeks, then i connected to internet, then stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #10: Duplicate id 0x7f050010, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
```

you are absolutely right about the error bieng the xml, but only because you are creating a new fragment that android is already holding on the stack.

instead of creating a new fragemtn you want to use a FragmentManager

```
FragmentManager fman=getFragmentManager();

fman.popBackStack();
```

itll be something along these lines.... for more exact code....

```
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().
                    .findFragmentById(R.your id here);
                if (fragment != null && fragment.isInLayout()) {

                  fman.beginTransaction().show(fragment)
                } else {
                  Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(your container-the file the error is coming from that holds all you fragments, fragment)
                      fman.beginTransaction().show(fragment)

                }
```