# open a fragment on Button Click throws InflateException?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception

i am trying to get simple fragment on button click. but i get InflateException and app crashes instantly. found several answers in StackOverflow and no one worked for me. hope anyone can help me out with explanation.

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22653341/binary-xml-file-line-10-error-inflating-class-fragment/22654167),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874882/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-error-inflating-class-fragment),[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424040/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-10-error-inflating-class-f)

**MainActivity.class**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Line 16

    button.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewfragment();
        }
    });

}

public void viewfragment()
{
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    BlankFragment1 fragment = new BlankFragment1();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment1, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    .......
    ......
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />

<Button>
    ......
<Button/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**blank_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#654"
android:id="@+id/thisisfframent"
tools:context=".BlankFragment"
android:orientation="vertical" />
```

**BlankFragment.class**

```
public class BlankFragment1 extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blank_fragment, container, false);
   }
}
```

**Error log**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.berunda.audio.fragmentact, PID: 28350
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.berunda.audio.fragmentact/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2638)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:196)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:561)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:437)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.berunda.audio.fragmentact.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6444)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:196) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:809)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:731)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:825)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:537)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:437) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.berunda.audio.fragmentact.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6444) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:196) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742) 
 Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment .BlankFragment1: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:632)
    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:596)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2228)
    at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:98)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:5751)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:781)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:731) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:862) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:825) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:537) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:437) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.berunda.audio.fragmentact.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6444) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1116) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2720) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:196) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1538) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:210) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5982) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:852) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:742) 
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class ".BlankFragment1" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.berunda.audio.fragmentact-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.berunda.audio.frag
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the error stacktrace

Comment: error stacktrace added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the fragment at runtime then you need to change your activity_main.xml  to following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    .......
    ......
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    />

<Button>
    ......
<Button/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: not the static way.i want programmatically add fragment. as described in developer page  [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#java)

Comment: I have updated the answer, just change your <fragment> tag to <FrameLayout>

Comment: Yes. it worked..Thanks lot..but there is no indication about FrameLayout on developer page right?..somehow it worked..Thanks again.